# Keep Static IP Routes after Network Unreachable error?

Tags: networking, routing, iproute

I am use iproute2 to route traffic from one VM via another in a networking simulation, all involved VMs are running Ubuntu 16.

`ip route add default via 172.22.0.3`

If I "unplug" the VM from its simulated network and then attempt to ping an external IP address (e.g. 8.8.8.8) I get the error:

`connect: Network is unreachable`

When I plug the VM back into the simulated network. This error remains unless I run the command again:

`ip route add default via 172.22.0.3`

Is there any way to persist a default IP route even after a network is made unreachable?

Edit: To clarify what "unplugging" the devices means... In this case it is logically akin to taking a pair of scissors to the Ethernet cable between the two VMs. This virtual Ethernet cable is provided by a specialized tool which routes traffic between a TUN interface on each VM.

Comment: Does the interface still exist after "unplugging"? If not, then it's impossible.

Comment: The interface does still exist even after the "unplugging" based on the output of ifconfig.

Comment: OK... does the interface retain its IP address? When an IP address is changed (or removed) then routes via that interface are also removed. Exception are point to point interfaces (e.g. `ppp0`), with those it's possible to set a route pointing simply to the interface.